# Extra columns in sql select query or view

Tags: mysql, sql, database, calculated-columns

So i currently got 3 tables in my database,
One containing information about members, one about their boats (length) and one about prices.

**Lid (Member)**

[image: Member Table]

**Schip (Boat)**

[image: Boat table]

**Tarief (Prices)**

[image: Prices]

I need to create a query that combines parts of these tables, but i have not found any way how to do this. This is what my 'new' table / select statement result should look like:
[image]

- Where Naam should be Lid.Naam (from the 1st table)
- Where Adres should be Lid.Adres (from the 1st table)
- Where Email should be Lid.Email (from the 1st table)
- Where contributie should be Tarief.Bedrag where Soort = 'contributie'
- Where liggeld should be (Tarief.Bedrag where Soort = 'liggeld') x (Schip.lengte) and if Lid.Schip is empty, this amount should be 0
- Where totaal should be liggeld + contributie
- At last, everyone who has lid.ContributieBetaald = 'ja' should not be in the list

I hademade an example for how it should look like if the query works completely:
[image: How it finally should look like]

If anyone knows how to create a query for this or a view and would like to help me, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with this? `(Tarief.Bedrag where Soort = 'liggeld')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.Naam, l.Adres, l.Email, 
(SELECT Bedrag FROM Tarief WHERE Soort = 'contributie' LIMIT 1) AS 'Contributie',
(SELECT Bedrag FROM Tarief WHERE Soort = 'liggeld' LIMIT 1)*IFNULL(s.length,0) AS 'Liggeld',
(SELECT Bedrag FROM Tarief WHERE Soort = 'contributie' LIMIT 1)+
(SELECT Bedrag FROM Tarief WHERE Soort = 'liggeld' LIMIT 1)*IFNULL(s.length,0)  AS 'Totaal'
FROM Lid l
LEFT JOIN Schip s ON l.Schip=s.Naam
WHERE l.ContributieBetaald <> 'ja';
```

Comment: I'm a always a bit concerned when it comes to sub-selects in select list. I'd like to make sure no sub-select returns more one than row. (max/limit/whatever)

Comment: You are right regarding the limitation to one column. What I got from the presented information is that Tarief is some kind of configuration table and the column Soort will be the unique column, that is why I did not take it into account.  However, I will add the LIMIT statement to the subqueries to make the query better. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I'm getting this error:
SQL Fout (1370): execute command denied to user ''@'localhost' for routine 'test.NVL'